# Validation Rules on Opportunity object

Tags: validation

I would like to restrict a user from moving an Opportunity stage to Closed Won if a checkbox field called Total Spend is unticked.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as Error Condition Formula:

```
Total_Spend__c = false && ISPICKVAL( StageName , 'Closed Won')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of guides out there relating to creating validation rules within salesforce.

[Here is the salesforce documentation describing the basics of validation rules.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm)

The basic principle of a validation rule is that if the condition specified is met the validation rule will stop the record being saved and produce an error message.

In your example you would need to create a rule which looks at the StageName and your custom **Total Spend** field (for this example i'll call it `Total_Spend__c` )

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( StageName , 'Closed Won'), NOT(Total_Spend__c) )
```

The above formula will check to see if the `StageName` is Closed Won and the `Total_Spend__c` field is false, if so it will stop the record being saved.

Comment: `StageName` is a picklist and can't be compared the way you did - you have to use `ISPICKVAL` or `TEXT` formula